# how to valilidate a condtion for list in JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-framework-version, jsonserializer

I have a JSON file, where i have to perform a data validation based on a json element.

below is my json file

```
[
  {
    "id": "5241585099662481339",
    "displayName": "Music",
    "name": "music",
    "slug": "music",
    "imageUrl": "http://mno.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "6953585193220490118",
    "displayName": "Celebrities",
    "name": "celebrities",
    "slug": "celebrities",
    "imageUrl": "http://ijk.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "5757029936226020304",
    "displayName": "Entertainment",
    "name": "entertainment",
    "slug": "entertainment",
    "imageUrl": "http://pqr.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "3718",
    "displayName": "Saturday Night Live",
    "name": "saturday night live",
    "slug": "saturday-night-live",
    "imageUrl": "http://efg.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "8113008320053776960",
    "displayName": "Hollywood",
    "name": "hollywood",
    "slug": "hollywood",
    "imageUrl": "http://qwe.com"
  }
]
```

Below is code snippet

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyItem>>(json);

    if (list.Any(e => e.id =="3718")) 
    {
        //How do get the exact displayName on the if condtion 
    }    

    public class MyItem
    {
        public string id;
        public string displayName;
        public string name;
        public string slug;
        public string imageUrl;
    }
```

Here i want the displayname value based on the if condtion passed. So inside my if loop if put list.displayname i need the value to printed as **Saturday Night Live**

Answer (score 2):

```
// name will be null if there isn't any item where id == 3718
var name = list.FirstOrDefault(item => string.Equals(item.id, "3718"))?.displayName;

// InvalidOperationException will be  thrown if there isn't any item where id == 3718
var name = list.First(item => string.Equals(item.id, "3718")).displayName;
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this:

```
var name = list.Where(e=>e.id=="3718").Select(x=>x.displayName);
```